# Understanding the grammar behind ～かよ in 知るかよ and マジかよ etc

Tags: grammar, rhetorical-questions

I think that [知るかよ！](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%88) means "like I would know!"/"hell, if I know!" and that [マジかよ！](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B8%E3%81%8B%E3%82%88/UTF-8/) means something like "[are you/is this] for real?"/"seriously?", but is there an underlying rule behind the ～かよ pattern seen at the end of sentences?

If I was to, for example, say （それを）食べるかよ, what kind of a meaning would it have?

Can ～かよ also be used as an ordinary question? Does it make a rhetorical question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`か` is a sentence final particle that makes a question, and `よ` is a sentence final particle that adds the subject's attitude. Ignoring the meaning added by `よ`, which does not affect the core meaning of the sentence, all of the sentences you have are questions. And in all of your examples, they are rhetorical questions.

> 知るかよ
> literally: 'Do I know/bother about it?'
> 'I don't know/bother about it!'
>
> まじかよ
> literally: 'Is that serious?'
> 'I can't believe it!'
>
> 食べるかよ
> literally: 'Will I eat it?'
> 'I won't eat it!'
>
> [欧米か!](http://youtu.be/Exbu7SbKg_k)

Note that the addition of `よ` adds subject's attitude, which makes it difficult to interpret the sentences as literal questions.

Comment: Note that `知るか。` / `食べる（もん）か！` are both easily recognizable as non-questions even without `よ`. However, `食べるのか` seems (to me) to be a literal question without `よ`.

Comment: `食べるのか` can be rhetorical in several ways: "Are you ever going to eat it?", "Am I supposed to eat it?", etc.