# Meaning of しかも and それで in Yes-No question

Tags: translation

I see that しかも and それで usually connect 2 sentence together. But I see them place at the beginning in Yes-No questions.

1)"しかも歌うんかい"

2)"それで上手いんかい"

Does it mean 1) "(Moreover) is he singing?" and 2) "(So) Is it good?" ?

Comment: These are probably not "questions" in the first place. What's the context?

Comment: The context: A boy is playing a guitar on the street. Then a bunch of yakuzas show up and take his guitar. Fortunately, a drunk man from nowhere suddenly appears and punch them in the face. He then sits next to the boy and ask him to play the song just now. The boy says: "What?You want to hear it?" (What a strange man) .Before he plays, the man starts to sing. The boy seems surprised and say: "Huh" "(しかも歌うんかい)" .More people start to gather around the 2 of them. The boy then say: "(それで上手いんかい)". After that, the boy want to form a band with him.

Comment: Closely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5177/7810

Answer (score 0):

I would say

１）しかも歌うんかい→（Moreover)　Is he singing? (in informal words, I would say 'is he singing lol') Is correct interpretation.

2) それて上手いんかい→ I would say this interpretation does not suffice. それで上手いんかい usually follows up after he/she has done something extraordinary before. In english interpretation, I will say '(after some extraordinary action) and he is good at it?'

Hope this helps.